# An $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function defined on $\mathcal{S}=\{\bigcup_{k\in K}E_k:K\subset\mathbb{Z^+}\}$ must be constant on each $E_k$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I have proved the following statement(s) and I would like to know if my proof is correct and/or how it could be improved, thanks.

"Suppose $X$ is a set and $E_1, E_2,\dots $ is a disjoint sequence of subsets of $X$ such that $\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k=X$. Let $\mathcal{S}=\{\bigcup_{k\in K}E_k:K\subset\mathbb{Z^+}\}$.

> (a) Show that $\mathcal{S}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra on $X$.

> (b) Prove that a function $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable if and only if the function is constant on $E_k$ for every $k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$.

My proof:

(a) If we take $K=\emptyset$ then $K\subset\mathbb{Z^+}$ so $\bigcup_{k\in K}E_k\in\mathcal{S}$ and $\bigcup_{k\in K}E_k=\emptyset$ so $\emptyset\in\mathcal{S}$.

Let $A\in\mathcal{S}$: then $A=\bigcup_{k\in K_A}E_k$ for some $K_A\subset\mathbb{Z^+}$ so $X\setminus A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}E_k\setminus\bigcup_{k\in K_A}E_k=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z^+}}E_k\setminus\bigcup_{k\in K_A}E_k=\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb{Z^+}\setminus K_A}E_k$ and $\mathbb{Z^+}\setminus K_A\subset\mathbb{Z^+}$ so $A\in\mathcal{S}$.

Let $A_1,A_2,\dots \in\mathcal{S}$: then $A_1=\bigcup_{k\in K_{A_1}}E_k, A_2=\bigcup_{k\in K_{A_2}}E_k,\dots, A_n=\bigcup_{k\in K_{A_n}}E_k,\dots$ so $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}\bigcup_{k\in K_{A_n}}E_k=\bigcup_{k\in K_{A_1}}E_k\cup\bigcup_{k\in K_{A_2}}E_k\cup\dots=\bigcup_{k\in K_A}E_k$, where $K_A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty} K_{A_n}\subset\mathbb{Z^+}$ so $\bigcup_{k\in K_A}E_k\in\mathcal{S}$ hence $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n\in\mathcal{S}$.

(b) $\fbox{$\Rightarrow$}$ Let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be an $\mathcal{S}$-measurable function and suppose for sake of contradiction there existed some $E_{K}, K\in\mathbb{Z^+}$ such that $f$ is not constant on it, ie $f(E_K)=\{y_1,y_2\}, y_1\neq y_2$: then since $\{y_1\}$ is a Borel measurable subset of $\mathbb{R}$ we have that $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})\in\mathcal{S}$ so $f^{-1}(\{y_1\})=\bigcup_{k\in K_{y_1}}E_k$ for some $K_{y_1}\subset \mathbb{Z^+}$ hence we have $E_K\cap\bigcup_{k\in K_{y_1}} E_k\neq\emptyset$ and since the $E_k$s form a partition of $X$ this can only be if $K\in K_{y_1}$ ie $E_K\subseteq\bigcup_{k\in K_{y_1}} E_k$ thus $f(E_k)=\{y_1,y_2\}\subseteq f(\bigcup_{k\in K_{y_1}}E_k)=\{y_1\}$, contradiction.
So, if $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ is $S$-measurable it must be constant on each $E_k, k\in\mathbb{Z^+}$, as desired.

$\fbox{$\Leftarrow$}$ Now, let $f:X\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function which is constant on each $E_k$, ie $f(X)=\{y_1=f(E_1), y_2=f(E_2),\dots,y_n=f(E_n),\dots\}$: then

- if $B$ is a Borel subset of $\mathbb{R}$ with $B\cap f(X)=\emptyset$ we have $f^{-1}(B)=\emptyset\in\mathcal{S}$;
- if $B\cap f(X)=f(X)$ we have $f^{-1}(B)=X\in\mathcal{S}$;
- if $B\cap f(X)\subsetneqq f(X), B\cap f(X)=\{y_{j_1},y_{j_2},\dots, y_{j_n},\dots \}, \{j_1,\dots,j_n,\dots\}\subset \mathbb{Z^+}$ we have $f^{-1}(B)=\bigcup_{k\in \{j_1,\dots,j_n.\dots\}}E_k\in\mathcal{S}$.

So since in all possible cases $f^{-1}(B)\in\mathcal{S}$ we can conclude that $f$ is $\mathcal{S}$-measurable, as desired.

Comment: It looks fine. I would not use the $\ldots$ after the fifth equality of the last paragraph of part (a). That step is not adding anything.